# OpenGL- Why drawing line in OnDraw function with passing parameters does not work?

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc, drawing

I am working on a MFC project and for 3d graphic I am using opengl;

in OnDraw() function I write this code :

```
            int idx1 = MarkerCoordinates[SourceMarkerIndex];
            int idx2 = MarkerCoordinates[SourceMarkerIndex + 1];
            int idx3 = MarkerCoordinates[SourceMarkerIndex + 2];

            int idx4 = MarkerCoordinates[DestMarkerIndex];
            int idx5 = MarkerCoordinates[DestMarkerIndex+1];
            int idx6 = MarkerCoordinates[DestMarkerIndex+2];

            glBegin(GL_LINES);

            glVertex3f(idx1,idx2,idx3);
            glVertex3f(idx4,idx5,idx6);

            glEnd();
```

because the user at runtime detemine the parameters to define a bone I must pass the parameters to the glVertex3f()(idxi , i = 1,2,...);however in this way, there is no line in output; if I explicitly pass integers to the glVertex3f it draw lines;

can you tell me where is my wrong?

Comment: Have you defined your frustum correctly? Is the line passing trough the frustum? 
With your openGL initialization code, it may be easier to found the problem.
Actually, I see 2 problems in your code, but they probably are not the source of you empty output: glBegin/glVertex are deprecated in OpenGL 3+, and glVertex3f is expecting float, but you feed it with integers.

Comment: I don't understand what is your meaning about frustum! I said that when I explicitly pass glVertex() a number it works but with parameter, does not work! with passing double to the glvertex the problem still exist ;)

Comment: If glVertex3f work with literal floats and idx feed it with the same values, it should work. Maybe check values that MakerCoordinates is feeding glVertex3f.

Comment: yes when I enter the numbers in form of double it works but its problem is that it draws the line from the destination point ...

Answer (score 0):

Call Invalidate() function to trigger WM_PAINT message, which in turn call OnDraw()